# When the coefficients can be rational?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, fiber-bundles, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have a linear combination of irreducible curves on a surface, but the coefficients are rational, then is it still possible to say that this divisor corresponds to some line bundle?

Comment: No, just think of the projective plane and $\frac{1}{n} H$ for a hyperplane.

Comment: What Mohan said. But you can make this work in some sense by passing to a finite cover of your surface. See the start of Chapter 4 of Positivity in Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: Thank you both, actually my problem is exactly what Nefertiti says, otherwise in normal situations I'm aware of the answer...